# Copying Without the Clipboard and Without Formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I've found a way to copy ranges from one workbook to another in Excel 2013/2016 without using the clipboard.

The problem is that the formatting of the source data is also being copied as well. I only wanted to copy the values.

I am combining data from daily workbooks into a weekly workbook. There are two workbooks:

1. `workbookDailyTrain1` (one daily workbook every 24 hours, each has 2 sheets: "Day" and "Night")
2. `workbookWeeklyTrain1` (this has 1 sheet: "Train1")

Here is the line in question:

```
workbookDailyTrain1.Sheets("Day").Range("A13:B24").Copy workbookWeeklyTrain1.Sheets("Train1").Range("C5:D16")
```

Is there a way to modify this line of code to make it such that the range values only are being copied across? The destination workbook has its own formatting which has to be kept at all times for the purposes of SharePoint Server deployment.

Answer (score 5):

Just set the two ranges' values equal to the other:

`workbookWeeklyTrain1.Sheets("Train1").Range("C5:D16").Value = workbookDailyTrain1.Sheets("Day").Range("A13:B24").Value`

Comment: You can also run a `pastespecial pastevalues`

Comment: @nutsch - True, but if we're trying to avoid Copy/Paste (clipboard), then you wouldn't do `PasteSpecial`.

Comment: Hello Bruce, apologies for the late reply here - I had issues logging in for some time. Thank you very much for this. Really appreciate it. Aaron